# How to sort in Java via Spark using the MapReduce functions

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

Hi I'm looking for a way to do a simple sort in Spark (using Java code) and using map reduce. I'm very new to this so a good explanation of how map/reduce works would be really extremely helpful. I've read some explanations that were okay but didn't talk about code at all which is more helpful to me.

I have an input data file which millions of ascii 100 byte records/or better yet 100 byte binary records.  I want to sort on the first 10 bytes of each record/line. These files are about 10 TB, so it's a lot of data and I'm not sure what the fastest way to do this is. How would I go about doing this with map/reduce. Java is not my language so writing out the actual code would be extremely helpful.

All I'm doing now is

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkSimpleSort");
sparkConf.setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:19000/hdfsfiles/ASCII500Mill", 10);
lines.sortBy( new Function<String, String>() 
    {  
        @Override
        public String call( String value ) {
          return value.substring(0,10);
        }
    },true,1);


jsc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:19000/hdfsfiles/ASCII500Mill", 10);
jsc.stop();
```

EDIT: So I'm still working on this, and really need help. I can perform the map function fine, create the keys, but then shouldn't I be able to just call sortByKey at that point? I read a somewhat similar question/answer on SO and it seems that the reduce step is necessary still. I just don't really understand that "why" or "how" of what these calls are doing, and what I can do to make this the most simple "MapReduce sort" algorithm I can make. I just need map().reduce().sortByKey() or whatever ordering I would need to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT2: I also see that people using map on a text file are usually (from what I've seen) been splitting a text file into individual words (what other people normally do with map and textfiles, and what's given as an example on the Spark Doc/Guide site). I'm already sorting on the lines (not individual words), so maybe I don't need map? I know I'm sorting by key, but that's no reason to do more than return a "mapped" RDD of the input file using each line by the first 10 bytes. But then again, I lose track of the original lines offset/position. Sorry about the ignorance here, I'm not used to programming in Java, especially the delegates, even though they're similar to C#, and not used to FlatMap or Spark so I'm way way way out of my element here. Again, any help, greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: even if there is a map and a reduce function in spark, you should know that mapreduce and spark are two different things. you cannot run spark in mapreduce or mapreduce in spark

Comment: yeah I know that. Spark and Hadoop's bread and butter seem to be map\reduce transforms. I just don't know how to use them properly, and I don't know what's going on under the hood when those calls are made. I'm not saying one thing is the same as the other though. What gave you that impression? Just curious .... Also for those reading, I do know that I can perform lines.map() or .flatmap() and .map().reduce() and then apparently sortbykey(), but I don't know exactly how to use it. There's map maptopair maptodouble flatmap reduce reducebykey sort sortbykey, etc.

Comment: Yeah Hadoop (HDFS) is what I'm using for a filesystem as I can create a bunch of cluster nodes to split the work. Spark is like my front end type deal. I get what you're saying though. all cleared up ... now i just wish someone could help :(

Answer (score 0):

I found that this sorts, although it's not doing it by the first ten bytes of the record, rather by creating a map/dictionary with numbers to record, counting then sorting. It's not exactly what I wanted, but it should help anyone who comes here. I pulled the map/reduce part from spark documentation.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import scala.*;

public class JavaSparkPi {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkPi");
    sparkConf.setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:19000/hdfsfiles/500mill", 10); 
    String s = lines.first();
    System.out.println("First element in UNsorted array: " + s);
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = lines.mapToPair(p -> new Tuple2(p, 1));
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
    JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> sorted = counts.sortByKey();

    s = lines.first();
    System.out.println("First element in sorted array: " + s);
    lines.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:19000/hdfsfiles/500millOUT4");    
    jsc.stop();
  }
}
```